# How to develop my own .NET controls?

Tags: c#, memory-management, custom-controls, gdi+

I've been struggling for a long time with basic controls that Windows Forms offers to developers, but... right now, I am developing an application that requires more advanced control than normal "TextBox".

Since, at this time, my application is about memory management, I have to show in the form, the process memory in bytes (or other type of data) to the user, giving it the ability to modify it as he wants.

The problem comes here, because... if I show the data in a TextBox, it only allow me to display the data in read-only text because if I let the user modify the textbox directly, it will be very messy and unaesthetic.

I was reviewing some projects on SourceForge about C# and the handling of hexadecimal data, and i found a good project, called [Be.HexEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/), which has a control developed and designed by its creators, but in GDI+.

The control is called HexBox, and that's just what I need to get.

Do any of you know how to develop a control like this?... I would greatly facilitate things. What kind of manuals/books should I read to learn this kind of development? I ask this because I ignore everything about GDI+.

Or... is there other way for do it?

Comment: GDI+ is the basic way of drawing in WinForms. I don't see how you've written any non-trivial WinForms applications *without* using methods of the `Graphics` class.

Comment: @CodyGray In fact, you're right. I have not developed advanced and/or important applications in WinForms (Beyond simple windows, where I limited myself to using the controls of the .NET platform). But now that I want to do a different application, I feel the need to learn GDI+ to basic or deeper things, as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a textbox to show to the user the current value and another textbox to enter the desired value (maybe a slider will work better).

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. He's asking for resources on how to create custom controls in .NET WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it's GDI+ that you have to learn

http://www.amazon.co.uk/GDI-Programming-Creating-Controls-Programmer/dp/1861006314

You may still be able to write controls in WPF and then include them somehow into your winforms app, but if you need to push pixels GDI+ is the only way.

Comment: That book's a bit old. It was written for the .NET 1.0 Framework. I'm sure everything it says is still *accurate* as far as it goes, but it misses out on a lot of useful stuff that's been added.